# Issues with Trix editor in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, text, action, trix

I'm having this issue with the Trix editor in rails 5.2.4 with webpacker.
The only thing I can see is a little box at the left of the 'Save' button.

[image]

My Gemfile has this gem installed:

```
gem'actiontext',github:'kobaltz/actiontext',branch:'archive',require:'action_text'
```

And installed the trix editor with:

```
rails action_text:install
```

And finally, this is the html code:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-3">
   <%= link_to 'Back', posts_path, class:'btn btn-secondary mb-4' %>
   <div class='card'>
     <div class='card-body'>     
       <h4 class='card-title'>Editing post</h4>
       <%= render 'form', post: @post %>
     </div>           
   </div>             
 </div>               
<div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <%= form_with(model: [@post, @paragraph]) do |form| %>
      <%= form.hidden_field :element_type, value: 'paragragh' %>
      <%= form.submit 'Paragraph', class: "btn btn-primary" %> 
    <% end %>        
  </div>
  <% @post.elements.each do |element| %>
    <% if element.persisted? %> 
      <%= form_with(model: [@post, element]) do |form| %>
        <%= form.rich_text_area :content %>
        <%= form.submit 'Save', class: "btn btn-primary" %> 
      <% end %>      
    <% end %>        
  <% end %>          
</div>
```

Comment: Does this post help? https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form/issues/1638

Comment: Ya it isn't being initialized by the looks of it.  I bet there are js errors in the console if you inspect it.  You could also just view the page source and I bet the js ins't being loaded. This post helped me at first, it tells you everything running the install does.  Maybe hunt those down and see what is missing, https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/10/01/rails-6-action-text.html

Comment: The links provided by you Thang and Rockwell Rice point to Rails 6 and GoRails states that with Rails 5.2 I may have issues. I'll try with Rails 6 to find out.

Comment: Well, I changed rails version to 6 and that made it.